# In R Bins the dataframe according to fixed interval size and sum respective occurrences of values with lower and upper bins value

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having following `dt` dataframe.

```
dt <- data.frame(
  No= c(14000,17000,48452,94632,36541,20000,100000,46241,78941,32464,69872,90000))
```

The expected output should be

```
       No             bin lower  upper freq
1   14000 [1e+04,1.5e+04] 10000  15000    1
2   17000 (1.5e+04,2e+04] 15000  20000    2
3   20000 (1.5e+04,2e+04] 15000  20000    2
4   32464 (3e+04,3.5e+04] 30000  35000    1
5   36541 (3.5e+04,4e+04] 35000  40000    1
6   46241 (4.5e+04,5e+04] 45000  50000    2
7   48452 (4.5e+04,5e+04] 45000  50000    2
8   69872 (6.5e+04,7e+04] 65000  70000    1
9   78941 (7.5e+04,8e+04] 75000  80000    1
10  90000 (8.5e+04,9e+04] 85000  90000    1
11  94632 (9e+04,9.5e+04] 90000  95000    1
12 100000 (9.5e+04,1e+05] 95000 100000    1
```

Comment: Your input dataset gives me error

Comment: See this updated input dataframe.

Here, upper value is also missing. It must be included in last bins of dataframe(all No should be in non scientific format)

Comment: Edit your question removing the wrong lines and put the good ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
seq.no <- seq(10000, 100000, by=5000)
dt <- data.frame(
  No= c(14000,17000,48452,94632,36541,20000,100000,46241,78941,32464,69872,90000)) 

dt <- dt %>% arrange(No) %>% 
  mutate(
    bin = cut(No, breaks=seq.no, include.lowest=TRUE), 
    lower = seq.no[findInterval(No, seq.no, left.open=TRUE)],
    upper = seq.no[findInterval(No, seq.no, left.open=TRUE)+1])

dt.freq <- group_by(dt, bin) %>% summarize(freq=n())
dt %<>% left_join(dt.freq)
```

**EDIT**
For earlier versions of R, where `findInterval` doesn't have `open.left` argument, use the following in the `mutate` step.

```
dt <- dt %>% arrange(No) %>% 
  mutate(
    bin = cut(No, breaks=seq.no, include.lowest=TRUE), 
    lower = seq.no[length(seq.no)- findInterval(-No, -rev(seq.no))],
    upper = seq.no[(length(seq.no)- findInterval(-No, -rev(seq.no))) + 1]
)
```

Comment: -@adibender. I am getting following error.Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  unused argument (left.open = TRUE)

Comment: @Mahesh That is strange, did you run the code in a new R session? I just ran the code in a fresh R Session and had no errors.

Comment: What R Versioin do you have?

Comment: R  version- 3.2.3

Comment: I see, there has been an update to the `findInterval` function in recent R versions. If you update to 3.3.2 the code should work.

Comment: In 3.2.3 the `findInterval` function didn't have the `open.left` argument, therefore the error

Comment: Is there any other options to do findInterval other than R version update. Else, any other method to perform this task?

Comment: @Mahesh see **EDIT**